# Is it possible to install 3rd party Carplay into Chevrolet Equinox 2013?

Tags: dashboard, equinox, navigation

I have an Equinox and I want to upgrade to CarPlay. The interior looks like this:

[image: 2013 Equinox interior]

Is it possible to upgrade to a 3rd party CarPlay solution? Being new to 3rd party add ons, I'm not sure how that would work with the space there is or what would need to be removed or changed.

Comment: Do carplay offer adaptors for your vehicle?

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though you could add a third party CarPlay-compatible receiver to your vehicle. A quick search on the Crutchfield site shows me [at least 50 options](https://www.crutchfield.com/g_300/All-Car-Stereos.html).

Even if you do not choose to purchase from them, their site is a great source for market research.

*Full disclosure: this is what I did on my 2004 WRX and I used a receiver from Crutchfield.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a module to it which adds wireless CarPlay / Android Auto.  [www.gromaudio.com](http://www.gromaudio.com) $660 retail